# Wrong EXIF data when uploading directly from camera

Tags: metadata, android

Given a webform where I can upload a photo I have two different outcomes.

1 When uploading a picture that was taken earlier, the EXIF data of the uploaded picture contains orientation "top left". The picture is being displayed correctly.

2 When uploading a picture using the camera directly the EXIF data contains orientation "right top". The picture is now displayed rotated sideways

The phone was in the exact same position in both situations.

Is there a reason that the orientation in situation 2 is different. Or is it a bug in Android/Phone?

Edit: added EXIF data from both pictures:

Picture stored on phone:

```
Filename - rechtop.jpg
ImageWidth - 198180864
ImageLength - 264241152
Make - Google
Model - Pixel 6a
Orientation - Top left
XResolution - 72
YResolution - 72
ResolutionUnit - Inch
Software - HDR+ 1.0.514217843zd
DateTime - 2023:04:06 13:05:56
YCbCrPositioning - Centered
Exif-IFD-Offset - 318
GPS-IFD-Offset - 898
OffsetTime - +02:00
OffsetTimeOriginal - +02:00
OffsetTimeDigitized - +02:00
Lens Make - Google
Lens Model - Pixel 6a back camera 4.38mm f/1.73
ExposureTime - 1/99.9 seconds
FNumber - 1.73
ExposureProgram - Normal program
ISOSpeedRatings - 210
ExifVersion - 0232
DateTimeOriginal - 2023:04:06 13:05:56
DateTimeDigitized - 2023:04:06 13:05:56
ComponentsConfiguration - YCbCr
ShutterSpeedValue - 1/100 seconds
ApertureValue - F 1.73
BrightnessValue - 2.15
ExposureBiasValue - 0.00
MaxApertureValue - F 1.73
SubjectDistance - 0.23 m
MeteringMode - Center weighted average
Flash - Flash not fired, compulsory flash mode
FocalLength - 4.38 mm
SubsecTime - 831
SubsecTimeOriginal - 831
SubsecTimeDigitized - 831
FlashPixVersion - 0100
ExifImageWidth - 3024
ExifImageHeight - 4032
InteroperabilityOffset - 868
SensingMethod - One-chip color area sensor
SceneType - A directly photographed image
CustomRendered - Custom process
ExposureMode - Auto
White Balance - Auto
DigitalZoomRatio - 0 x
FocalLengthIn35mmFilm - 27 mm
SceneCaptureType - Standard
Contrast - Normal
Saturation - Normal
Sharpness - Normal
SubjectDistanceRange - Macro

GPS information: - 
GPSImgDirection - 0.00/0.00

Thumbnail: - 
Compression - 6 (JPG)
Orientation - Top left
XResolution - 72
YResolution - 72
ResolutionUnit - Inch
JpegIFOffset - 1100
JpegIFByteCount - 30503
```

Picture uploaded directly:

```
Filename - gedraaid.jpg
ImageWidth - 3024
ImageLength - 4032
Make - Google
Model - Pixel 6a
Orientation - Right top
DateTime - 2023:04:06 13:08:14
Exif-IFD-Offset - 148
OffsetTime - +02:00
ExposureTime - 1/99.9 seconds
FNumber - 1.73
ISOSpeedRatings - 163
ShutterSpeedValue - 100 seconds
ApertureValue - F 1.73
SubjectDistance - 0.20 m
Flash - Not fired
FocalLength - 4.38 mm
SubsecTime - 047
ExifImageWidth - 3024
ExifImageHeight - 4032
SubjectDistanceRange - Macro 21
```

Comment: What are the full EXIF data in each case? Sending pictures from a camera usually rips out some of the Exifs for privacy.

Comment: @xenoid: Added the EXIF data of both pictures

Comment: If the picture in portrait or landscape?

Comment: It is in portrait. Also reflected in width and length.

Comment: This is weird. On my current Android phone (and IIRC on all my past an present Android phones....) portrait photos are encoded in landscape (which I assume is the sensor format) with an Exif flag for rotation (unless they have been edited on the phone).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some instances of where *tilt* can confuse the camera as to the image orientation... i.e. when the camera is (near enough) parallel to the ground there is no "UP" or "TOP" relative to the sensor height/width.

Comment: Phone was almost vertical in both instances. Don't think this is the issue.